# How to convert SVG file to an equivalent GDI+ object?

Tags: c++, winapi, svg, gdi+, msxml

I am looking to convert an SVG file to an equivalent GDI + object using C++. Once I get this object I can render it. Is there a suggestion for the same?

My requirement is I should not use any third party C++ library? I should use only Micosoft's Libraries?

I can parse the SVG file using MSXML. After parsing the SVG file how to convert it to GDI+ object?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility, that an SVG cannot be expressed in terms of GDI+ objects? While you can render an SVG image using GDI+, it is likely not possible to store sufficient information in a GDI+ object to be rendered later on. A [GraphicsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534456.aspx) may be helpful, but cannot represent each and every SVG image. See [Overview of Vector Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536368.aspx) and the following sections to get a better understanding.

Comment: How to convert SVG file to rasterized image format (bmp, png) using C++ without using any third party library?

Comment: Well, that's easy. Just write your own SVG rasterizer then. In a few months you should have a basic implementation up and running. Another 6 months an it'll run reliably. Alternatively, you could explain, what you really want. Your question and the last comment are asking for different things.

Comment: GDI+ objects supports rasterized image format and metafiles.If I convert SVG file to rasterized image format then I can render it that's why I asked that question in the last comment.

Comment: Without using 3rd party libraries you will have to write your own SVG parser, and render it to an image you can use with GDI+. That makes this question too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: @IInspectable: Is there a way for the OP to embed web browser control that would render SVG for him? Just a thought...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: The [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041.aspx) doesn't support rendering SVG content. It requires that external viewer extensions (like the discontinued Adobe SVG Viewer) are installed. Since the question is asking for a solution that doesn't require 3rd party libraries, this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

SVG is a complex API and not especially easy to work with. If you can reduce your problem to a small subset of SVG, you may have a chance to get something working.